# How to solve boot in Laptop/Notebook after cloning Windows 7 64bits OEM from HDD to SDD?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, ssd

I have cloned my HDD to SSD. The files can be seen when the SSD is plugged in as external device, but the SSD itself will not boot.

**My original system:**

```
Laptop Acer Aspire 5733-6432
Windows 7  64 bits (fully updated)
Proc. Intel i5-480M
RAM 4Gb DDR3
HDD 500GB Samsung SATA 2,5"

New SSD 480GB Kingston SATA 2,5"
```

**The steps I took were:**

1. Run **Macrium Reflect** as following log.
2. Choose to clone partitions 2 and 3, respectively:

- Partition 1: Active partition, MBR, 100MB, original size, placed at start;
- Partition 2: Primary partition, boot and system, full remaining size of SDD;
- The original 1st partition was not copied. It is called PQService and serves as repairing partition.

3. Physically changed my HDD to SSD into the Laptop, and reboot the system.

**Notes:**

1. There is no UEFI/Legacy option in the setup. It must not matter as both disks are MBR.
2. The booting order was SSD, DVD reader, USB FDD, USB HDD, Network.
   Windows cannot boot from USB, but it should not matter. The sole device capable of booting was the SSD attached to motherboard's SATA connection and it was set to be the first option. The BIOS recognize the SSD normally.
3. Operational system is OEM. I suspected that the license might be restricted to the HDD, but Microsoft asures the change to SDD is valid.
4. The SSD size differs from HDD.

What should I do next?

```
Log:
    Clone ID - 9D2D3C52E03E185F 
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dismounting drives 
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Starting Clone - 27 August 2020 18:57 
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Creating volume snapshots 
     Volume Snapshots Created 
     C:\ \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy1 
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Source Disk: MBR Disk 1 [88820153] - ST950032 5AS 0001 <465.76 GB> 
     Geometry: 60801\63\512 
     BPB: 255\63\512 
     Destination Disk: Disk 2 [00000000] - Mass Storage Device <447.13 GB> 
     Clone Type: Intelligent sector copy 
     Verify: Y 
     Delta: N 
     SSD Trim: Y 
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Operation 1 of 2 
    Copy Partition: 2 - SYSTEM RESERVED  
    NTFS 38.2 MB / 100.0 MB 
    Destination: 
    Start Sector: 2,048 
    End Sector: 206,847 
    Partition Type: Active 
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Checking file system 
    Processing: \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0 
    Clone completed successfully 
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Operation 2 of 2 
    Copy Partition: 3 - Acer (C:) 
    NTFS 146.98 GB / 447.66 GB 
    Destination: 
    Start Sector: 206,848 
    End Sector: 937,701,375 
    Partition Type: Primary 
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Checking file system 
    Loading the NTFS $MFT File 
    Copying data 
    Processing: \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy1 
    Writing partition table 
    Copying MBR and track 0 
    Writing Master Boot Record (MBR) 
    Clone completed successfully 
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     BCD Update - No active partition copied 
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Clone completed in 03:27:49 
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     I/O Performance: Read 150.5 Mb/s - Write 157.5 Mb/s 
    Macrium Reflect v7.2.5107
```

Comment: Mention your exact problem a little more precisely!!!

Comment: @Madhubala What information did I miss?

Comment: it's kind of of unclear what is your objective ; will suggest you to summarise your question in a line or two with your objective

Comment: @Madhubala Cloned HDD into SSD. Cannot boot from SSD. I could not identify the problem as described above. What is the problem and how do I solve it?

Comment: what happens/error you get when you try to boot from cloned SSD

Comment: @Madhubala Erro screen after POST: "The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible." As far as I know, this is caused by error in MBR, but I cloned it into the first partition.